# How do you take data from a file and edit it in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a library database in Python. I have most of it done, but I do not know how to edit the data for each book entry. Here is my code so far:

```
#imports os modules

    import os

    #checks to see if library folder exists. if not it makes one. either way it moves the working directory to it
    if os.path.exists('library') != True:
        os.mkdir("library")
        os.chdir("library")
        print(os.getcwd())
    else:
        os.chdir("library")
        print(os.getcwd())

    #intilizes infinite loop
    while True:
        #gets operation from user
        op = input('What would you like to do? (insert new book, retrive book data, edit book data, list all books, delete a book): ')
        #if you want to make a new book entry a file is created with information gathered from the user
        if op == 'insert new book':
            title = input('what is the title of the book?: ')
            author = input('what is the author of the book?: ')
            isbn = input('what is the ISBN?: ')
            nb = open(title + ".txt", "w")
            nb.write(title )
            nb.write(author + ' end, ')
            nb.write(isbn + ' end, ')
            nb.close()
            title = ''
            author = ''
            isbn = ''
        #if you want to display the book data it displays the file content
        elif op == 'retrive book data':
            title = input('what is the title of the book?: ')
            cb = open(title + ".txt", "r")
            print(cb.read())
            cb.close()
            title = ""
        #deletes the book entry
        elif op == "delete a book":
            title = input('what is the title of the book?: ')
            os.remove(title)
            title = ""
        #here is where i need
        elif op == 'edit book data':
```

Comment: would using SQL be complicated? :)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and replace your **full code** with a [mcve]. Because if you just post the *real problem* instead of your code, your question would be more clear and answerable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This script solves your problem. It uses SQL database, because it's way more efficient and easier to use. I hope it's easy enough to understand, consulting sqlite3 documentation wouldn't hurt if you want to learn more.

Before you run it, make sure that the .db file exists, replace tablename with name of your table in the .db file and that Title, Author and ISBN are your headers. You probably want to have them all set as text with this code, I thnk you'd have to make a small change if you wanted ISBN to be an integer.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#imports

import os
import sqlite3

#To find where the script is ran from
script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
#Path relative to the script leading to .db file
rel_path = "database/library.db"
#Starting to work with database
database = sqlite3.connect(os.path.join(script_dir, rel_path), timeout=1)
db = database.cursor()
database.row_factory = sqlite3.Row

def main():
    op = input("What would you like to do? Choose number\nOptions: 1: Insert new book, 2: retrieve book data, 3: edit book data, 4: delete a book:\n")
    if op == "1":
        insertbook()
    elif op == "2":
        retrievebook()
    elif op == "3":
        editbook()
    elif op == "4":
        deletebook()
    else:
        print("Please insert valid choice (1, 2, 3 or 4)")

def insertbook():
    print("You chose to insert a book\n")
    title = input('what is the title of the book?:\n')
    author = input('what is the author of the book?:\n')
    isbn = input('what is the ISBN?:\n')
    db.execute("INSERT INTO tablename VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (title, author, isbn))
    print("Book '%s' added\n" % title)

def retrievebook():
    print("You chose to retrieve a book\n")
    title = input('what is the title of the book?:\n')
    db.execute("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE Title = ?", (title,))
    book = dict(db.fetchone())
    print("Book: %s, Author %s, ISBN %s\n" % (book['Title'], book['Author'], book['ISBN']))

def deletbook():
    print("You chose to delete a book\n")
    title = input('what is the title of the book?:\n')
    c.execute("DELETE FROM tablename WHERE Title=?", (title,))
    database.commit()
    print("Book '%s' deleted\n" % title)

def editbook():
    print("You chose to edit a book\n")
    title = input('what is the title of the book?:\n')
    author = input('what is the author of the book?:\n')
    isbn = input('what is the ISBN?:\n')    
    db.execute("UPDATE tablename SET Author = ? ISBN = ? WHERE Title = ?", (author, isbn, title))
    database.commit()
    print("Book '%s' edited\n" % title)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you encounter any syntax errors, I run python 2.7, so I might have done something wrong with python 3 printing.

Also I'm not entirely sure that the code is SQL injectproof, but since you have a command to delete a book, I doubt a malicious user will try and abuse your code.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do something like

```
elif op == 'edit book data':
    optitle = input('Type the title of the book to be modified: ')

    #the following puts all lines in an array called "lines"
    cb = open(optitle + ".txt", "r")
    lines = cb.readlines()
    cb.close()
    # Now we print each line and ask to enter the new value:
    lines[0] = input('the current title is '+ lines[0] +', please type the new one: ')
    lines[1] = input('the current author is '+ lines[1] +', please type the new one: ')
    # etc....
    #finally we write all back to the file, 
    nb = open(title + ".txt", "w")
    foreach line in lines:
    nb.write(line)
    nb.close()
```

However, you should really use a database as @iScrE4m said.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new file and give it your data:

```
with open('your_file.txt', 'w') as ef:
    ef.write('Your initial data\n')
```

You can open your existing file and give it your extra data:

```
with open('your_file.txt', 'a') as ef:
    ef.write('Your extra data\n')
```

By the way, working with files use **with**. It closes your file automatically.